# Firestore Python SDK - count() aggregation

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, aggregate-functions, firebase-admin

I'm using Firebase Firestore in my Python project (with their [official Python SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python)) and having trouble performing count() aggregation. This funciton is supported according to their [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries). However, they do not provide Python example ( they do in other parts of documentation ). I tried to play with it in Python console, tried something like this:

```
query = db.collection('videos').where('status', '==', 'pending')
query.count()
```

without any luck. So I'm wondering how is it possible to implement? Does Python SDK support this functionality?

Comment: I don't see anything mentioned in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/python) so I don't think it's supported for Python SDK yet,.

Comment: That sounds like an answer @Dharmaraj :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Update:

`count()` query is now available in Firebase Admin SDK from [version 6.1.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/python#version_610_-_02_february_2023).

---

Firebase Admin Python SDK doesn't support that query yet. You can still use the [runAggregationQuery REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/runAggregationQuery) meanwhile. The Google Cloud [Firestore Python SDK](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-firestore/) has Aggregation result types available from `v2.7.0+` so it should be available in Admin SDK soon.

Comment: The `count()` queries are (finally!) here, but unfortunately the doc is still unclear about how to use it. Here is however the solution to the OP: `count=query.count().get() ; nb_docs=count[0][0].value`.    `query` can be any query or just a collection, as usual.

Answer (score 2):

Although the API for this purpose is not fully ready but it's coming along. If you don't wanna use the REST API as suggested by @Dharmaraj, you can do something like this for now:

```py
from google.cloud.firestore_v1.services.firestore import FirestoreClient
from google.cloud.firestore_v1.types.document import Value
from google.cloud.firestore_v1.types.firestore import RunAggregationQueryRequest
from google.cloud.firestore_v1.types.query import (
    StructuredAggregationQuery,
    StructuredQuery,
)

Aggregation = StructuredAggregationQuery.Aggregation
CollectionSelector = StructuredQuery.CollectionSelector
Count = Aggregation.Count
FieldFilter = StructuredQuery.FieldFilter
FieldReference = StructuredQuery.FieldReference
Filter = StructuredQuery.Filter
Operator = StructuredQuery.FieldFilter.Operator


client = FirestoreClient()
project_id = ""
request = RunAggregationQueryRequest(
    parent=f"projects/{project_id}/databases/(default)/documents",
    structured_aggregation_query=StructuredAggregationQuery(
        structured_query=StructuredQuery(
            from_=[CollectionSelector(collection_id="videos")],
            where=Filter(
                field_filter=FieldFilter(
                    field=FieldReference(
                        field_path="status",
                    ),
                    op=Operator.EQUAL,
                    value=Value(string_value="pending"),
                )
            ),
        ),
        aggregations=[Aggregation(count=Count())],
    ),
)

stream = client.run_aggregation_query(request=request)

print(next(stream).result.aggregate_fields["field_1"].integer_value)
```

Output:

```
1
```

Generally the following would work to count the total number of documents in a collection:

```py
def count_documents(collection_id: str) -> int:
    client = FirestoreClient()
    project_id = ""
    request = RunAggregationQueryRequest(
        parent=f"projects/{project_id}/databases/(default)/documents",
        structured_aggregation_query=StructuredAggregationQuery(
            structured_query=StructuredQuery(
                from_=[CollectionSelector(collection_id=collection_id)]
            ),
            aggregations=[Aggregation(count=Count())],
        ),
    )

    stream = client.run_aggregation_query(request=request)

    return next(stream).result.aggregate_fields["field_1"].integer_value


print(count_documents(collection_id="videos"))
```

Output:

```
10
```

Make sure that you have `google-cloud-firestore>=2.7.3` and also remember to set the value of `project_id` variable in the `count_documents` function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is possible:

```
count_value = firestore_client.collection(f"UserRecommendatedQuotes").count().get()[0][0].value
```